# Need help to optimize the code for alogorithmix problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am trying to solve the problem "Subarray with given sum" on Geeksforgeeks. My code is giving correct outcomes but the time taken is exceeding the limit. 
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/subarray-with-given-sum/0
I can't figure out how to optimize it more than this.

```
for j in range(int(input())):
    x,y = map(int,input().split())
    numbers = list(map(int,input().split()))
    result =0
    stack=[]
    location=[]
    for index,i in enumerate(numbers):
        while i+result>y:
            if stack:
                a=stack[0]
                stack= stack[1:]
                location=location[1:]
                result = result-a
        if i+result < y:
            result+=i
            stack.append(i)
            location.append(index+1)
        elif result+i ==y:
            print(location[0],index+1)
            break
    if result+i != y:
        print(-1)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only thing I could think of is to remove the lists, and store the start of the subarray. If you change the `if stack`to `if result`it should work.

```
for j in range(int(input())):
    x,y = map(int,input().split())
    numbers = list(map(int,input().split()))
    result =0
    start=0
    for index,i in enumerate(numbers):
        while i+result>y:
            if result:
                a=numbers[start]
                start += 1
                result = result-a
        if i+result < y:
            result+=i
            start += 1
        elif result+i ==y:
            print(start,index+1)
            break
    if result+i != y:
        print(-1)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score -1):

Keep track of the total/accumulated sum up to that point in the list. Then the sum of nums[i:j] is equal to total sum up to (including) j minus sum (not including) i.

```
def sumsub(nums, target):
  sums = [0] # the accumulated sum of the list of nums
  for i, num in enumerate(nums):
    sums.append(num + sums[i])
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    for j in range(i, len(nums)):
      if sums[j + 1] - sums[i] == target:
         return i, j

print(sumsub([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 15))
print(sumsub([1, 2, 3, 7, 5], 12))
```

```
(0, 4) # 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
(1, 3) # 2 + 3 + 7 = 12
```

Comment: You are using a lot of loops, which will increase the time complexity.